# Collapsing/Expanding filters in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard with several worksheets embedded in it. I am displaying multiple filters from different worksheets in the dashboard. Is there a way to hide/ unhide all the filters together as an when it is required. I am publishing my dashboard on to tableau server.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You should vote [here](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1662) for this functionality. But as a workaround you an give a try to @StuartMatthews's trick.

Comment: Depending on your requirement, you could use an action filter to cover the unwanted filters with a white box (or whatever your background colour is) and unhide this box when a selection or highlight is made.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hacky way to do this, similar to what Ben P mentioned in comments.
It's based on two tricks.

1. use a parameter to show/hide a blank sheet.
2. use floating panel with (-)ive X or Y coordinates, this panel is the home of the blank sheet in (1) and your quick filters. The (-)ive coordinates makes the panel invisible since it's rendered outside the page.

The only time the filters become visible is when the blank sheet in (1) is shown (actually it's off-screen) which 'pushes' the quick filters 'into' the visible area of the screen.
The parameter in (1) acts as your expand/collapse quick filters control.

Please see [this video where its explained step by step.](https://vimeo.com/107352893)